# SwiftUI Insert a field name received from a function following "."

Tags: swift, swiftui, insert, func, dot

I get a field name from a function. How to insert that field name following dot "."

1. Model

```
struct User: Identifiable {
        let username: String
        let fullName: String
        var description: String = ""
    }
```

2. Get a field name from a title

```
extension User {
    func get_field_name(key: String?) -> String {
        var default_field = ""
        guard let key = key else { return default_field }
        let field: [String: String] = [
            "Name" : "fullName",
            "Username" : "username",
            "Bio" : "description"
        ]
        return field[key] ?? default_field
    }
}
```

3. Expect.

**Example if "item.title" is "Name" then**

```
let user: User
Text(item.title) //OK - Name
Text(user.get_field_name(key: item.title)) //OK - fullName
Text(user.???) //??? How to insert field name following "."
```

4. Purpose

*I use it in the pic below*

[image]

**Thank you so much for your answer.**

Comment: I don’t understand what you want to do with the last Text example. What is it supposed to show in the view? Do you mean you want to display the value of that field from your user object?

Comment: Exactly @JoakimDanielson

Comment: Then you have the answer below I believe.

Comment: Yes. Thanks for your attention to my question @JoakimDanielson

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you are looking for key paths.

Change `get_field_name` to:

```
func getUserKeyPath(key: String?) -> KeyPath<User, String>? {
    guard let key = key else { return nil }
    let field: [_: KeyPath<User, _>] = [
        "Name" : \.fullName,
        "Username" : \.username,
        "Bio" : \.description
    ]
    return field[key]
}
```

Then you can do:

```
if let keyPath = getFieldKeyPath(key: item.title) {
    Text(user[keyPath: keyPath])
} else {
    // handle the case when item.title does not match any property name in User
}
```

You can also do this in a single expression if you want to show a default string in the `Text` when `item.title` does not match any property name:

```
Text(getFieldKeyPath(key: "Name").map { user[keyPath: $0] } ?? "Unknown")
```